# Dart, the best way to create types with method

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem and I don't know how to do it.
I need to have several types: blue, red, green, black.
These types must have const like 'blue.title' 'blue.RGB'.
And these types must be able to be integrated as a constant of a class.
E.g.

```
Block myBlock = new Block(blue);
```

What is the best way to do it?
Please forgive my ignorance I am new

Comment: Can you provide more information about how you intend to use this types and methods? Are they just some kind of data classes which holds some constant values which you can use? Maybe write some pseudo code which shows what you want.

Comment: Here is an example of pseudo code.

`Red.title --> 'Red'`
`Block blockA = new Block(Red);`
`blockA.type ---> Red`
`blockA.type.RGB ---> [255,0,0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
void main() {
  const block = Block(Color.red);

  print(block.type.title); // Red
  print(block.type.RGB); // [255, 0, 0]
}

class Block {
  final Color type;

  const Block(this.type);
}

class Color {
  static const Color red = Color('Red', [255, 0, 0]);
  static const Color green = Color('Green', [0, 255, 0]);
  static const Color blue = Color('Blue', [0, 0, 255]);
  
  final String title;
  final List<int> RGB;

  const Color(this.title, this.RGB);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of something like that.
Do you know if it's possible to make every MyColor under a keyword like Color:
`const block = Block(Color.Red);`? Ty

Comment: Updated the example. I have moved the constants into the `Color` class itself (which has been renamed from `MyColor`),

Comment: Great, thanks.
I'll have to learn OOP properly.